# How to create an animation by changing images after a certain amount of time

Tags: ios, animation

Hello guys I am new to xcode and I am trying to animate balloons on touch by changing its images: this is my code:
now the problem i am facing is its not animating images means the animation timer is not working: please guide me what should i do to animate the images with time: if I am not doing it properly then please guide me that how can i do it by NSTimer?

```
-(void)baloonbursting:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if ([[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbaloons.png"] isEqual:button.currentImage]) {
    NSLog(@"em redbaloons.png");
    UIImage *bubbleImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redburst.png"];
    [button setImage:bubbleImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^(){
    // define animation
    if ([[UIImage imageNamed:@"redburst.png"] isEqual:button.currentImage]) {
        NSLog(@"em redbaloons.png");
        UIImage *bubbleImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redburst2.png"];
        [button setImage:bubbleImage3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }   
}
 completion:^(BOOL finished){
 // after the animation is completed call showAnimation again
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             [button removeFromSuperview];
                         }}];
                 }];
```

}

Comment: I don't think the image property of UIButton can be animated.

Comment: guide me how can i do it by NSTIMER?

Comment: Why are you creating UIImage's in your if's just to check for image equality, couldn't you just use the `name` property of the image?

Comment: actually i got 5 different images of balloons and on bursting balloons there are images for their matching colors this is why i am checking for image equality

Comment: You can only animate `animateable` properties, and the image of a button is not. If I understand correctly, you do not want to animate the images, but to exchange them after some time. Let me know if that is correct and I will write a small code snippet for you that does the job with NSTimer.

Comment: yes exactly you got my point i just want to change the image with small passage of time.

Comment: @Javier Quevedo-Fernández yes exactly you got my point i just want to change the image with small passage of time.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at: http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/

Comment: @Steve the solution that Mick posted is correct, although it is exemplified using only two images. Is there a reason why you don't like that one? Do you really need one with timers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want you to give you a solution to show you the right direction to think. That is, why I developed a small test project in Xcode and I controlled that this code really works.

First: forget NSTimers for this animation!

The idea is, that you "play" around with subviews, because you can change their alpha properties from 0.0 (invisible) to 1.0 (fully opaque), which are supported by the SDK's view animations.

Please change the image names according to your own file names (I've used my own here).

The following method checks, if the button's image is that one that shall invoke an animation - exactly what you did before. If this condition is met, it visually animates the change of the button's image to another image:

```
- (IBAction)balloonBursting:(UIButton *)sender
{
    BOOL doAnimate = NO;

    UIImageView *ivOldBubbleImage;
    UIImageView *ivNewBubbleImage;

    if ([[UIImage imageNamed:@"BalloonYellow.png"] isEqual:sender.currentImage]) {
        NSLog(@"will animate");
        doAnimate = YES;

        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BalloonPurple.png"];
        ivNewBubbleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
        ivNewBubbleImage.alpha = 0.0;
        ivOldBubbleImage = sender.imageView;
        [sender addSubview:ivNewBubbleImage];
    }

    if (doAnimate) {
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^(){
            // define animation
            ivOldBubbleImage.alpha = 0.0;
            ivNewBubbleImage.alpha = 1.0;
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [sender setImage:ivNewBubbleImage.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                             [ivNewBubbleImage removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
    }
}
```